How to make input fields size immutable to padding changes?
I have a problem with the input fields causing increase on the height property when the padding is increased on them via function triggers from events. I want the size of the input fields to remain immutable regardless of the font and padding change through functions:
I tried setting the fixed height and box-sizing to border-box as shown above but the padding still increases the input height.


function focusInput() {
  for (let i of inputs) {
    i.style.padding = '1rem 1rem 2rem';
  }

  style.innerHTML = style.innerHTML.replace(
    /\.input::placeholder\s*\{[^}]+\}/,
    '.input::placeholder { font-size: 12px; }'
  );
}

function clearInput() {
  for (let i of inputs) {
    i.style.padding = '';
  }

  style.innerHTML = style.innerHTML.replace(
    /\.input::placeholder\s*\{[^}]+\}/,
    '.input::placeholder { font-size: 14px; }'
  );
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

.form {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(70, 125, 179, 1) 0%, rgba(2, 31, 59, 1) 100%);
  padding: 5em;
  border-radius: 6em 1em 6em;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 3em;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.input {
  height: 3rem;
  min-width: 14rem;
  width: 70%;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}
<div class="form" id="forma">
  <h1>Sign Up</h1>
  <div id="inputs" style="line-height: 2.5em">
    <input class="input" type="email" name="emailOrPhone" placeholder="Email or phone number" />
    <input class="input password" type="password" placeholder="Password" maxlength="12" oninput="validateLength()" />
    <p class="error" id="error1"></p>
    <input class="input password" type="password" placeholder="Re-enter password" maxlength="12" oninput="isMatch()" />
    <p class="error" id="error2"></p>
  </div>




I don't think that is achievable while increasing padding and keeping same height. You can do is change padding of left and right only.

Replacing the .innerHTML of a <style> element is probably the least efficient way to change an element's appearane I've seen so far this week. Instead just add/remove CSS classes to elements to effect the adding-or-removal of CSS property values as-needed rather than mutating (and invaldiating) the entire browser's style rule state.

I tried using the Interactive Snippet demo in your post, but the input elements maintain a constant size and appearance for me - I see nothing wrong.

Estimated cause
your style of input
padding: 1rem; /* all */

in JS style of input
i.style.padding = '1rem 1rem 2rem'; /* top, right & left, bottom */

suggestion
check this
https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/CSS/padding
